# Crude difference vs effect size

Tags: effect-size, differences

Let's assume I have two groups of animals with the following weights and the average difference of 8 kilograms:

[image]

**Could you explain in layman's language, how the calculate difference differs from the effect size?**

May I say something like that:

A statistical test/technique adds uncertainty to the difference, meaning that it allows me to make inferences about the same difference in the whole population?

Comment: A crude difference *is* a possible effect size. A crude difference would be the preferred ES in some circumstances, but in others, it would be difficult to interpret -- which would lead someone to use another ES.

As to your question about statistical testing, I just asked a very similar question.